# Dependency Parsing using MaltParser and NLTK

Tags: parsing, dependencies, nltk

Consider the sentence

```
new_sent = '''PeterParker loves MaryJane.'''
```

I'm trying to parse this sentence by using malparser and NLTK as follows:

```
maltParser = nltk.parse.malt.MaltParser(working_dir="/Applications/maltparser-1.7.2", 
                                        mco="engmalt.linear-1.7",
                                        additional_java_args=['-Xmx1024m'])
graph = maltParser.raw_parse(new_sent)
print(graph.tree().pprint())
```

The result is

```
(. PeterParker loves MaryJane)
```

but the correct answer should be:

```
(loves PeterParker MaryJane .)
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong here? Does anyone could help me?